# How to run futures on the current actor's dispatcher in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

Akka's [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future) warns:

> When using future callbacks, such as onComplete, onSuccess, and onFailure, inside actors you need to carefully avoid closing over the containing actor’s reference, i.e. do not call methods or access mutable state on the enclosing actor from within the callback

It seems to me that if I could get the Future which wants to access the mutable state to run on the same dispatcher that arranges for mutual exclusion of threads handling actor messages then this issue could be avoided. Is that possible? (Why not?)

The `ExecutionContext` provided by `context.dispatcher` is not tied to the actor messages dispatcher, but what if it were? i.e.

```
class MyActorWithSafeFutures {
  implicit def safeDispatcher = context.dispatcherOnMessageThread

  var successCount = 0
  var failureCount = 0

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case MakeExternalRequest(req) =>
      val response: Future[Response] = someClient.makeRequest(req)
      response.onComplete {
        case Success(_) => successCount += 1 
        case Failure(_) => failureCount += 1 
      }
      response pipeTo sender()
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do that in Akka?

(I know that I could convert the above example to do something like `self ! IncrementSuccess`, but this question is about mutating actor state from Futures, rather than via messages.)

It looks like I might be able to implement this myself, using code like the following:

```
class MyActorWithSafeFutures {
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = new ExecutionContextExecutor {
    override def execute(runnable: Runnable): Unit = {
      self ! runnable
    }

    override def reportFailure(cause: Throwable): Unit = {
      throw new Error("Unhandled throwable", cause)
    }
  }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case runnable: Runnable => runnable.run()
    ... other cases here
  }
}
```

Would that work? Why doesn't Akka offer that - is there some huge drawback I'm not seeing?

(See https://github.com/jducoeur/Requester for a library which does just this in a limited way -- for Asks only, not for all Future callbacks.)

Comment: In all honesty, I would avoid at all costs mutating state inside of an actor from within a Future callback.  It just smells bad from the get go.  Piping a message back to yourself is going to be your safest bet.  It's a good and safe practice so I'm not sure why you are avoiding it.  Trying to get into the underpinnings of how threads are assigned to actors is only going to lead to trouble...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rkuhn explains why this would be a bad idea [on the akka-user list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/0lZcXkckTdw):

> My main consideration here is that such a dispatcher would make it very convenient to have multiple concurrent entry points into the Actor’s behavior, where with the current recommendation there is only one—the active behavior. While classical data races are excluded by the synchronization afforded by the proposed ExecutionContext, it would still allow higher-level races by suspending a logical thread and not controlling the intermediate execution of other messages. In a nutshell, I don’t think this would make the Actor easier to reason about, quite the opposite.

Comment: And see https://gist.github.com/odd/e356e178bfa178f727e3 for an implementation of the "local" dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

Your actor is executing its `receive` under one of the dispatcher's threads, and you want to spin off a `Future` that's firmly attached to this particular thread? In that case the system can't reuse this thread to run a different actor, because that would mean the thread was unavailable when you wanted to execute the `Future`. If it happened to use that same thread to execute `someClient`, you might deadlock with yourself. So this thread can no longer be used freely to run other actors - it has to belong to `MySafeActor`.

And no other threads can be allowed to freely run `MySafeActor` - if they were, two different threads might try to update `successCount` at the same time and you'd lose data (e.g. if the value is 0 and two threads both try to do `successCount +=1`, the value can end up as 1 rather that 2). So to do this safely, `MySafeActor` has to have a single `Thread` that's used for itself and its `Future`. So you end up with `MySafeActor` and that `Future` being tightly, but invisibly, coupled. The two can't run at the same time and could deadlock against each other. (It's still possible for a badly-written actor to deadlock against itself, but the fact that all the code using that actor's "imaginary mutex" is in a single place makes it easier to see potential problems).

You could use traditional multithreading techniques - mutexes and the like - to allow the `Future` and `MySafeActor` to run concurrently. But what you really want is to encapsulate `successCount` in something that can be used concurrently but safely - some kind of... Actor?

TL;DR: either the `Future` and the `Actor`: 1) may not run concurrently, in which case you may deadlock 2) may run concurrently, in which case you will corrupt data 3) access state in a concurrency-safe way, in which case you're reimplementing Actors.

Comment: "this particular thread" -- No, I don't need a single thread dedicated to this Future, I want the existing exclusion mechanisms which apply to actor messages for this Actor to apply to the Future callback. Perhaps an auto-generated synthetic actor message or something?

Comment: "you're reimplementing Actors" -- no, I want to use the existing Actor framework, just without the boilerplate needed to convert the above example into actor messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [PinnedDispatcher](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html#Types_of_dispatchers) for your `MyActorWithSafeFutures` actor class which would create a thread pool with exactly one thread for each instance of the given class, and use `context.dispatcher` as execution context for your `Future`.

To do this you have to put something like this in your `application.conf`:

```
akka {
  ...
}
my-pinned-dispatcher {
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  type = PinnedDispatcher
}
```

and to create your actor:

```
actorSystem.actorOf(
  Props(
    classOf[MyActorWithSafeFutures]
  ).withDispatcher("my-pinned-dispatcher"),       
  "myActorWithSafeFutures"
)
```

Although what you are trying to achieve breaks completely the purpose of the actor model. The actor state should be encapsulated, and actor state changes should be driven by incoming messages.

Comment: "what you are trying to achieve breaks completely the purpose of the actor model." -- I don't think so. The above example is trivially transformable into a correct Actor implementation by replacing the Future callbacks with `self ! IncrementSuccess` message posts, and moving the logic out of the Future callback and into a "receive" case on the actor. I'd just like to avoid that boilerplate while keeping Actor mutable state safety.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question directly, but rather offers an alternative solution using [Akka Agents](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/agents.html):

```
  class MyActorWithSafeFutures extends Actor {

    var successCount = Agent(0)
    var failureCount = Agent(0)

    def doSomethingWithPossiblyStaleCounts() = {
      val (s, f) = (successCount.get(), failureCount.get())
      statisticsCollector ! Ratio(f/s+f)
    }

    def doSomethingWithCurrentCounts() = {
      val (successF, failureF) = (successCount.future(), failureCount.future())
      val ratio : Future[Ratio] = for {
        s <- successF
        f <- failureF
      } yield Ratio(f/s+f)
      ratio pipeTo statisticsCollector
    }

    override def receive: Receive = {
      case MakeExternalRequest(req) =>

        val response: Future[Response] = someClient.makeRequest(req)
        response.onComplete {
          case Success(_) => successCount.send(_ + 1)
          case Failure(_) => failureCount.send(_ + 1)
        }
        response pipeTo sender()
    }
  }
```

The catch is that if you want to operate on the counts that would result if you were using `@volatile`, then you need to operate inside a Future, see `doSomethingWithCurrentCounts()`.

If you are fine with having values which are eventually consistent (there might be pending updates scheduled for the Agents), then something like `doSometinghWithPossiblyStaleCounts()` is fine.

Comment: Thanks, this is one way to do the same thing using Actors which has a lot more boilerplate. My question here is that it seems like it should be possible to avoid this boilerplate if we can get the Futures into the same scheduler as the Actor's message queue -- how can I do that?